# Change text of twentyseventeen_edit_link()

Tags: theme-development, translation

Where do we go, or what do we do in order to change the default text displayed as `Edit` for the given function `twentyseventeen_edit_link()` which is originally part of the tweentyseveteen theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`twentyseventeen_edit_link()`](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/inc/template-tags.php) function returns an accessibility-friendly link to edit a post or page. Here is its content:

```
function twentyseventeen_edit_link() {
    $link = edit_post_link(
        sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
            __( 'Edit<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            get_the_title()
        ),
        '<span class="edit-link">',
        '</span>'
    );
    return $link;
}
```

Since it doesn't provide a hook or filter, you have to use [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/) to translate Twenty Seventeen's translation files. Everything you need is included in the PoEdit official site.

Comment: Jack thank you so much for the insight!  Is there anything wrong with replacing that function with `edit_post_link('[edit this page]', '<p>', '</p>');` in your opinion?  This is for my child theme.

Comment: the function `twentyseventeen_edit_link()` is 'pluggable' https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions therefore you can simply redefine it in functions.php of your child theme.